# How to get only 1 user available in group - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with Users that are in Projects, Those projects are in groups. Now I need a table to see how many users are available per group. I Use

```
COUNT(DISTINCT User_ID) AS UsersInGroup
```

This works fine. But now I also want to know of those users who are in a group who is available to take a call:

```
SUM(IIF(Slot_ID = 1 AND Status != 'Call', 1, 0)) AS AvailableForCall
```

The problem with this line is that it's not distinct and I don't get it right. Can someone please help me fix this line of code

I've created an SQLFiddle here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/22537/1

edit: Expected Output

```
+---------------+--------------+-------------------+
| Project_Group | UsersInGroup | AvailableForCalls |
+---------------+--------------+-------------------+
| A             |            2 |                 1 |
| B             |            1 |                 1 |
+---------------+--------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: show your expected output

Comment: You cannot get what you want because it does not make sense logically. Your `test_table` contains two unique users. However user `1` is contained in rows where their `Status` is both 'Call' and ''. So you can count that user as either available or not. You need to change your schema as you can't get the desired results with your flat table structure..

Comment: How many calls can a user take/have at the same time, altogether and per slot?

Comment: Only 1 call and always on slot 1

Comment: ...but your SQL Fiddle has three rows for user 1 on slot 1 - one is on call and the other two are available...?

Comment: So this mean if any status is 'Call' for a user on one of the slots then the user is not available for any calls.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Exactly!

Answer (score 1):

it seems you need below

```
SELECT
  [Project_Group],
  COUNT(DISTINCT [User_ID]) AvailableForCall

FROM
  test_table
  where Slot_ID = 1 AND Status != 'Call'
GROUP BY
  [Project_Group]
```

Comment: This doesn't provide the right answer, see the updated question

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your line-

```
SUM(IIF(Slot_ID = 1 AND Status != 'Call', 1, 0)) AS AvailableForCall
```

With and try-

```
COUNT(DISTINCT(IIF(Slot_ID = 1 AND Status != 'Call', [User_ID], NULL)))  AS AvailableForCall
```

Check fiddle [HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/22537/20)

Comment: This doesn't provide the right answer, see the updated question